# Writing an enum case check to a Bool variable without Equatable conformance

Tags: swift, enums

I have an Enum with associated values like this one:

```swift
enum SomeState {
    case loggedOut(redirectAfterLogin: Module? = nil)
    case loggedIn
}
```

Now in some cases I want to compare two states exactly (like are both logged out and also is the redirect target equal) and sometimes I just want to know if they are both logged out. My question regards the second case: I want to check if the state is logged out **and write that to a variable**, but obviously I can't implement `Equatable` to just account for the general case ignoring the parameters.

One way of achieving this would be to implement a computed property `isLoggedOut` on the Enum itself, but since this here is just an example and my actual code is much larger, this is not an option for me.

A second way (the one I currently use) is this:

```swift
func whatever() {
    if case .loggedOut = self.state {
        self.isLoggedOut = true
    } else {
        self.isLoggedOut = false
    }
}
```

This works, but I would rather write something like this:

```swift
func whatever() {
    self.isLoggedOut = (case .loggedOut = self.state)
}
```

Am I missing something or is it really not possible to write the case comparison of the `if`-clause to a variable directly (or some similar one-line-solution)?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to change `whatever` to be a computed property rather than a function, modify the assignments to `isLoggedOut` to be `return` statements and you've got your `isLoggedOut` property.

```
var isLoggedOut: Bool {
    if case .loggedOut = self.state {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Simplified example code where the type holding the `state` property defines the `isLoggedOut` property as well:

```
enum SomeState {
    case loggedOut
    case loggedIn
}

struct User {
    var state: SomeState

    var isLoggedOut: Bool {
        if case .loggedOut = self.state {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote here: "One way of achieving this would be to implement a computed property isLoggedOut on the Enum itself, but since this here is just an example and my actual code is much larger, this is not an option for me."

So this is no solution for me although it obviously would work …

Comment: @BennoKress you misunderstood my answer. This isn't defined on the enum itself. This is defined on the type that has a `state` property, just like your `whatever` function. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Oh, I see. So technically it's a third solution, but then again, I have lot of cases and would need to implement a lot of those additional computed properties. I'm really wondering, if I just overlooked some simple possibility to assign the result of the `case .loggedOut = self.state` ... that has to be a Bool, but I just found no way to simply extract it into a variable.

Comment: @BennoKress in your question you clearly stated that you only need this one specific case, so it was quite hard not to misunderstand your actual requirements. If you need several cases like that, why don't you make your `enum` conform to `Equatable`? That seems like the most obvious choice. If you don't need to handle all cases, simply return  `false` in a `default` case in your `==` implementation.

Comment: My question contains just an example to make the problem more understandable. Having the enum conform to Equatable is not an option, because in general I have two kinds of use cases: some where the associated values matter and some (like in the example) where they don't matter. Having Equatable conformance would always neglect one of the use cases which is why i decided to implement Equatable to account for associated values, but then it leaves me with the problem that I would have to implement computed properties for every case or I have what I wrote in `whatever()`.

Comment: I don't think "Having the enum conform to Equatable is not an option" is true. Check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
enum SomeState {
    case loggedOut(redirectAfterLogin: Int? = nil)
    case loggedIn

    var isLoggedOut: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .loggedOut(_):  return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

var aState: SomeState = .loggedOut()

if aState.isLoggedOut {
    print("logged out")
} else {
    print("not logged out")
}
```

(I switched the associated value redirectAfterLogin to a simple scalar Int so it would compile for those of us who don't have the definition of your Module type. you'd need to switch it back.)

The trick here is the computed property isLoggedOut, which uses a switch statement that ignores the associated value for the loggedOut case.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote here: "One way of achieving this would be to implement a computed property isLoggedOut on the Enum itself, but since this here is just an example and my actual code is much larger, this is not an option for me."

So this is no solution for me although it obviously would work …

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to avoid using `SomeState` before `.loggedOut`. But even with that, this is way better than the option that's built into the language, which is in the other answers.

It's better if you can make `Module` and `SomeState` be `Equatable`, but not necessary.

```swift
public extension Mirror {
  /// Get the associated value from an `enum` instance.
  func getAssociatedValue<AssociatedValue>(
    _: AssociatedValue.Type = AssociatedValue.self
  ) -> AssociatedValue? {
    guard let childValue = children.first?.value
    else { return nil }

    if let associatedValue = childValue as? AssociatedValue {
      return associatedValue
    }

    let labeledAssociatedValue = Mirror(reflecting: childValue).children.first
    return labeledAssociatedValue?.value as? AssociatedValue
  }
}
```

```swift
/// Match `enum` cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// - Parameter makeCase: Looks like `Enum.case`.
public func ~= <Enum: Equatable, AssociatedValue>(
  makeCase: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,
  instance: Enum
) -> Bool {
  Mirror(reflecting: instance).getAssociatedValue().map(makeCase)
  == instance
}

/// Match `enum` cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// - Parameter makeCase: Looks like `Enum.case`.
public func ~= <Enum, AssociatedValue>(
  makeCase: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,
  instance: Enum
) -> Bool {
  let instanceMirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)

  guard let dummyCase = instanceMirror.getAssociatedValue().map(makeCase)
  else { return false }

  return
    Mirror(reflecting: dummyCase).children.first?.label
    == instanceMirror.children.first?.label
}
```

```swift
struct  {
  enum SomeState {
    struct Module { }

    case loggedOut(redirectAfterLogin: Module? = nil)
    case loggedIn
  }

  var isLoggedOut: Bool
  var state: SomeState

  mutating func whatever() {
    isLoggedOut = SomeState.loggedOut ~= state
  }
}
```

More example usage:

```swift
enum : Equatable {
  case tuple(cat: String, hat: String)
  case labeled(cake: String)
  case noAssociatedValue
}

let tupleCase = .tuple(cat: "", hat: "")
XCTAssertTrue(.tuple ~= tupleCase)

XCTAssertTrue( .labeled ~= .labeled(cake: "") )

let makeTupleCase = .tuple
XCTAssertFalse(makeTupleCase ~= .noAssociatedValue)

switch tupleCase {
case .labeled: XCTFail()
case makeTupleCase: break
default: XCTFail()
}
```