# Return generic type based on enum

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I'm trying to write a function for split testing that responds with a generic response when passed an enum value.

In the code below, when the `getSplit(forFeature:)` function is called, the `SplitResponse` varies depending on the `Feature` being passed in.

```
protocol SplitResponse {
    associatedtype T
    func split() -> T
}

enum Feature {
    case feature1 // split test = Feature1Split
    case feature2 // split test = Bool
}

enum Feature1Split {
    case splitA
    case splitB
    case splitC
}

func getSplit(forFeature: Feature) -> SplitResponse {
    switch feature {
    case .feature1: return Feature1Response()
    case .feature2: return Feature2Response()
    }
}

struct Feature1Response: SplitResponse {
    typealias SplitResponse = Feature1Split

    func getSplit() -> SplitResponse {
        // split logic
        return .splitA
    }
}

struct Feature2Response: SplitResponse {
    typealias SplitResponse = Bool

    func getSplit() -> SplitResponse {
        // split logic
        return true
    }
}

let split1 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature1).split()

switch split1 {
    case .splitA: // doSomething
    case .splitB: // doSomethingElse
    case .splitC: // doAnotherThing
}

let split2 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature2).split()

if split2 == true {
  // doSomething
} else {
  // doSomethingElse
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on `getSplit(forFeature:)` of `Protocol 'SplitResponse' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Q1. I believe the solution is to associate the `SplitResponse` type based on the `Feature` that is being passed in. How do I do this?

Q2. Is there a way to get rid of the `Feature1Response`, `Feature2Response` structs and `SplitResponse` protocol altogether? So that `getSplit(forFeature:)` returns `Feature1Split` or Bool directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind optionals you can also try a type-erased `AnyResponse`:

```
protocol SplitResponse {
    associatedtype T
    func split() -> T
}

struct AnyResponse {
    private struct Box<T> {
        let split: () -> T
    }
    private let box: Any
    init<Response: SplitResponse>(_ response: Response) {
        box = Box(split: response.split)
    }
    
    func split<T>() -> T? {
        guard let box = box as? Box<T> else {
            return nil
        }
        return box.split()
    }
}

enum Feature {
    case feature1 // split test = Feature1Split
    case feature2 // split test = Bool
}

enum Feature1Split {
    case splitA
    case splitB
    case splitC
}

func getSplit(forFeature feature: Feature) -> AnyResponse {
    switch feature {
    case .feature1: return AnyResponse(Feature1Response())
    case .feature2: return AnyResponse(Feature2Response())
    }
}

struct Feature1Response: SplitResponse {
    func split() -> Feature1Split {
        // split logic
        return .splitA
    }
}

struct Feature2Response: SplitResponse {
    func split() -> Bool {
        // split logic
        return true
    }
}

let split1: Feature1Split? = getSplit(forFeature: .feature1).split()

switch split1 {
    case .splitA:
        print("doSomething")
    case .splitB:
        print("doSomethingElse")
    case .splitC:
        print("doAnotherThing")
    case .none:
        print("nil")
}

let split2: Bool? = getSplit(forFeature: .feature2).split()

if split2 == true {
    print("doSomething")
} else {
    print("doSomethingElse")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done as you'd like. You'll need to use more enumerations.

```swift
extension Feature {
  enum Split {
    case feature1(Feature1Split)
    case feature2(Bool)
  }

  var split: Split {
    switch self {
    case .feature1:
      return .feature1(.splitA)
    case .feature2:
      return .feature2(true)
    }
  }
}
```

The language doesn't have great tools for using `split` as you'd probably like to, thereafter. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61734859/652038) for the kind of thing you'll need to do, to help with that, and let me know if you need further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use enums:

```
enum Feature {
    case feature1 // split test = Feature1Split
    case feature2 // split test = Bool
}

enum Feature1Split {
    case splitA
    case splitB
    case splitC
}

enum SplitResponse {
    case feature1Response(value:Feature1Split)
    case feature2Response(value:Bool)
}

func getSplit(forFeature feature: Feature) -> SplitResponse {
    switch feature {
    case .feature1: return .feature1Response(value: .splitA) // or some other split logic
    case .feature2: return .feature2Response(value: true)    // or some other split logic
    }
}

let split1 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature1)
if case .feature1Response(let value) = split1 {
    switch value {
     case .splitA: print ("splitA")
    case .splitB: print ("splitB")
    case .splitC: print ("splitC")
    }
} else {
    print ("Ooops - Did not expect other than feature1Response")
}

let split2 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature2)
if case .feature2Response(let value) = split2 {
    if (value) {
        print ("feature2 response is true")
    } else {
        print ("feature2 response is false")
    }
} else {
    print ("Ooops - Did not expect other than feature2Response")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not currently supported in Swift. Let's look at this line:

```
let split1 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature1).split()
```

It returns `SplitResponse` object, but it is just a pure protocol object without a concrete `associatedtype`. So when you call your `split`(which is getSplit in your `strut` objects, maybe a typo there?) function, the compiler has no chance to detect what is the return type. Swift compiler does not like that and that's the error you have.

Even though your two objects conform to the same protocol, there is no meaningful way you can use them together. For instance let's consider this case:

```
let split1 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature1).split()
let split2 = getSplit(forFeature: .feature2).split()
print(split1 == split2)
```

The `print(split1 == split2)` expression would be invalid, as the compiler can't really know what type is `split1` and `split2`. One can be a `Bool` the other `Feature1Split` type which would make the expression invalid. On the other hand both can be `Bool`s which would make the expression valid. But even we know that would be valid, the compiler has no chance to know that.